# -DCucumberOptions tag not overriding in command line

Tags: cucumber, cucumber-jvm, cucumber-java, cucumber-junit

If I am using `-Dcucumber.options`, it's overriding the tag value from my Runner class. But if I am using `-DCucumberOptions` its not overriding the tag value in my Runner class. Can anyone help me on this?

Comment: Please share an example on how you do it and which result you had hoped for.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to the official documentation [here](https://cucumber.io/docs/reference/jvm) under Configuration section.

Citing from there:

> Configuration options can also be overridden and passed to any of the
>   runners via the `cucumber.options` Java system property. For example, if
>   you are using Maven and want to run a subset of scenarios tagged with
>   `@smoke`:
>
> `mvn test -Dcucumber.options="--tags @smoke"`

Comment: Yes Eugene S cucumber.options is working but what I want to do is in runtime I want to get my tagname and store that tag into database but its not happening becoz in my eclipse what ever runner file I am giving and that tag only being retrieved but the tag I am passing through command prompt is running but not able to retrieve that tag.So, could you please suggest me